# If we simulate a universe just like ours, is there any experiment simulated life could do to verify it is being simulated?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reality, empiricism, introduction-to-philosophy

Akin to Einstein's principle of equivalence where the observer cannot tell if he or she is either in free fall or being accelerated (in a small enough region of spacetime); I'm wondering the same thing about a [simulated universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis).

Assume we simulate a universe with the same laws of physics, and in this universe life that is intelligent enough to do experiments emerges.

**Is there any conceivable experiment that can be done to 'touch' the metal of the computer that they are being simulated on?**

If it is possible to simulate a universe and the answer to the above question is 'no', then it is therefore plausible that we may never answer some questions about our reality.

Comment: What’s wrong with the Turing test?

Comment: @MarkAndrews What's wrong with the Turing test? Mostly the interlocutor. People are all too willing to impute sentience to chatbots. But I don't see how the Turing test would help us determine if we're in a simulation, or find our way out of it.

Comment: The equivalence principle tells us you cannot tell the difference between a uniform gravitational field and an accelerated reference frame. It does not compare free fall to acceleration. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle

Comment: The Turing Test is an operational test to designate the property of "intelligence" to a computational system. The question of whether or not the simulation hypothesis can be proven by physical experiment is a philosophy of science question. If a computer would pass the Turing Test, it might form an empirical backbone that our own consciousness is simulated; no one has designed a system that has ever gotten close to passing it.

Comment: @JD Computers have already passed the Turing test. All that was proven is that humans are gullible. There was the Eugene Goostman joke a few years back, and that Google engineer who thought an AI chatbot was sentient last month. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_Goostman

Comment: "*One thing we would expect to see if the universe is discrete is that it has something called “quantum jitter”. This jitter is the effect of space and time being pixelated... So far there has been none detected... We can go on proposing finer and finer experiments, but we will always fail... You can always propose an alternative simulation format that invalidates any experimental result*", [Andersen](https://medium.com/the-infinite-universe/you-cant-simulate-this-universe-a81106c66019).

Comment: @user4894 I'm sure there is software that could convince my 6-year old, but the industry consensus (and for good reason) is that no system has done it yet. See [The Turing test: AI still hasn’t passed the “imitation game”](https://bigthink.com/the-future/turing-test-imitation-game/). The article you cite says 'Warwick's claim that Eugene Goostman was the first ever chatbot to pass a Turing test was met with scepticism; critics acknowledged similar "passes" made in the past by other chatbots under the 30% criteria'.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on the method of simulation and the degree of sophistication you confer on the simulators.

Any possible detection requires us to surmise that our minds have been simulated in a way that allows us to notice inconsistencies. If we are programmed to carefully ignore the grainy parts of the picture, it is hopeless.  This is a "trope" in science fiction, very colorfully instantiated by the phrase ["I have seen the fnords."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fnord) If you have been programmed not to see them, you won't see them even when they are right in front of you.

So, suppose the simulators have not so programmed us.

Surmise something like a digital computer. It would be massively more sophisticated than our current computers. But it would have finite accuracy. Very much more accuracy than ours, but finite.

Consider a seriously naive simulation based on a rectangular grid of points. The x, y, z, and time of any event is thus a digital number of finite length. This has obvious implications.

- Two objects moving at the same speed but very small angle relative to eachother will separate in small steps based on the minimum resolution of the grid. If it does not show  up on your billiards table, then it will show up in your radio astronomy.
- Time measurements will similarly have finite minimum interval that can be measured.
- There will be directions that potentially show special behavior due to the grid being rectangular. This will involve such effects as one sees when passing a forest that has been planted on a rectangular grid. As you move by such a forest the trees line up some times, and don't at others. The same would be true with such a grid.

The result of such a naive grid would be that various things could become quite manifest if we knew to look for them.

A more sophisticated method of simulation, better than a simple grid, would be much more difficult to detect. There are lots of different methods to simulate physics, and each of them has different points at which the finite accuracy of the hardware will become apparent. This is often referred to as "catastrophic loss of accuracy." It often arises when two real numbers are subtracted. If the difference is meant to be close to the limit of accuracy of the two numbers, then the difference will have very little accuracy.

Examples of catastrophic loss of accuracy are rife in computer science. Basically, any time the result of a calculation is based on subtracting one number from another, and the two values are only different from eachother by a small amount, you can easily see [loss of accuracy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) Such situations arise in many places in our physical laws.

We could do a survey of such situations and search for situations where the result demonstrated some such loss of accuracy. This would be a situation where chaos resulted when it should not.

So, surmise a more sophisticated simulation. Suppose the simulation is aware of the measurements that busy experimenters are doing. And the simulation is smart enough to predict what we should observe according to the laws of physics in a real, non-simulated, world. After all, if we are smart enough to do that, presumably the simulation system we are running on is smart enough.

So the simulation could hide from us by proffering up the non-suspicious results at every measurement. The result would be that we would never detect any suspicious results.

To summarize: The possibility of detecting the simulation depends on the cleverness of the simulators, and the attention they pay to hiding themselves. If they are smart and work at it, we can't detect them.

Comment: Excellent answer, which could be improved by a few points.  I suggest a preamble, which cites Quine's principle that evidence always underdetermines theory.  Hence a simulation hypothesis is unrefutably in principle, as ever more elaborate special cases assumptions can be postulated for the simulation.  SO -- the criteria for credibility should not be "is it not refuted", but the Popperian "does the simulation hypothesis make testable predictions that it passes?"  You note several that it does NOT pass -- detectable gridding resolution, and chaos when physics requires numeric subtraction.

Comment: Note there are more failures of the simulation prediction.  One is the simulation model requires that consciousness be identical to some algorithmic operation -- yet algorithmic identity theories of consciousness have failed every testable case so far.  Another is that a simulated world should be calculable, which requires that it be coherent, yet our current science (and theory of knowledge) is pluralist.  Pluralist based logic systems are not coherent, hence cannot have unique calculations.

Comment: Logic appears to be pluralist in our universe too, which makes the "calculable/coherent" criteria basically impossible to meet.  https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/think/article/guide-to-logical-pluralism-for-nonlogicians/EDFDFA1C9EB65DB71848DABD6B12D877  Also our universe is indeterministic, both at the quantum level, and at the macro level.  None of these things are what one would expect for what the OP means by a simulation.

Comment: Of course, per Quine, one can always postulate somehow an ANALOG simulation, with math that resists small number subtraction errors, that cracks the Hard Problem and encodes consciousness, is robust with respect to the failure to coherently close, and is indeterministic, but somehow is still a simulation.  Nobody can refute a sufficiently lengthy list of special cases to avoid falsification.  But the simulations we are familiar with -- look to be refuted.

Comment: @Dcleve The quantum level and indeterminism can already be seen as hints to a simulation. I mean that basically is your smallest steps in terms of time, space, charge, etc. Similarly using random functions for things you haven't fully figured out is something you'd likely do in a simulation. Same for a lack of coherency (patches). The thing is we still would only recognize it as a deviation from the norm if we were aware of the norm. Otherwise it's just how the world is and I'm not sure we would get around that insight.

Comment: @haxor789 -- Yes, this point is true.  I was less comfortable treating indeterminacy as a negative test case, as I know models can include randomness.  the ADVOCATES of the simulation hypothesis however, at least the ones I have seen, tend to be advocates of the model being deterministic.  So this is just a test case for a more specific/most-common version of the hypothesis.

Comment: @Dcleve When your comments approach the length of my answer, I suggest you write your own answer.  The point about chaos is, if a simulation is digital it can exhibit chaos in a system that physically should not be chaotic. I once worked on a simulation of concentric cylindrical ring structures in an engineering system. The size of the gap (which size determined heat flow outwards)  between the outermost and next-to outermost rings was calculated by subtracting. When this value was very close to zero the results began to drastically jump up and down, a massively unphysical result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option: it's both possible to simulate/demonize (Cartesianwise) an entire world, and trick its inhabitants as such; except that it's also possible for consciousness, in various possible worlds (simulated or not), to have a direct intuition/perception of physical reality. The simulators try to trick their victim world; if the victims don't use their faculty of direct reality-perception, then they won't know they're being tricked; but if this power is used, the game is up, at least subjectively (objectively, the victims might be nevertheless still trapped on the gameboard).

Or perhaps all possible consciousness has this primitive capacity to directly know, without deductive or inductive argument, whether it is subject to a vast distortion of the kind at stake, such that this capacity is always active, hence as long as we are self-aware (or whatever) enough, we will notice the, "Yes, *this* is real; no, *that* is not," signal going off, and hence it is possible for the deception to go on for a little while but there will be a natural tendency for the victims to automatically end up knowing that they *were* being deceived. This is only subtly different a scenario, compared to the above (in the above, it is possible for the victims to always be deceived, because it is always contingent on the victims' decision if they will use their reality-detecting faculty; here, the faculty will activate itself eventually no matter what).

**Who is to gainsay those who might say that they really just know, directly, that they are not always hallucinating, or in a dream or simulation, or being deceived by evil gods?** The standard objection is that it is possible for this deception to take place. My standard rejoinder is: how do we know that this is possible? To be sure, this reply only works on the external-world skeptic who is actively committed to a thesis; for a skeptic more along the lines of someone who is just not sure and hence *is* noncommital, this reply is not appropriate (morally or factually). And so then, though, the person who says, "Well, I myself do have this direct knowledge," also does not gainsay the curious skeptic, since for the curious person, the problem is less whether someone else knows this or that, but whether the one person knows such things.

Anyway, if it is possible for there to be a direct reality-detector, maybe not in the physical world that we know, and maybe hardly conceivably in knowably imaginable worlds, but at least in some generically possible world, that's one option. A discursive test, I don't know about so much: there'd have to be some axiom that the victims could know by intellection, which gave them clear marks to check, on pain of invalid inference even, by which means the victims could differentiate between deceptive and legitimate content. Or, if we go a coherentistic route, the discursion could be a more "circular" or rather cyclical act; the derivation of, "I know that I am (usually) in a real world," or, "I know that my consciousness is not being empirically distorted in these extravagant ways," would not have to be rigorously step-by-step according to some metallic concept of logic, but these items of knowledge might organically evolve into and through our minds.

Outside of wacky mathematics conjectures, I haven't had much occasion to use coherentistic justification procedures, so I don't have a lot of experience(!) with how such reasoning goes vs. external-world skepticism, though.

**Addendum.** As far as an *experiment* could go... If the deceivers' world is based on our laws of physics (or whatever), then I guess it would have to be that there was a noticeable (somehow) difference between human-like brains being electrically manipulated and being exposed to genuine "external stimuli." But I still think that would be hard to cash out that notice as something besides, again, direct (or close to direct) reality-detection. I am reminded, though, of Hilary Putnam's semantic-externalist rejoinder to the broad problem: if all uses of a brain's (or hologram's?) concept of reality are being caused by electrical manipulation, it is hard to see how the more abstract side of that concept would be able to connect up adequately with its concrete dimension, in order to even be meaningful in the first place (as something applicable). If all my tree-sensations are deceptive, then my use of the word *tree* might nevertheless be faithful to the relative stability of my tree-sensations; *those sensations are ultimately all that I mean by use of words for trees.*

But: still not really an experiment. What *would* you do? As if by using holographic microscopes, your consciousness might still come to witness the quantum realm of the photons (and electrons?) maintaining the holograms, and by this means engage with the deceivers' level of reality? But so far, nothing in the scenario just described (the use of fake-but-real microscopes) seems to directly indicate that the victims at least know the truth of quantum field theory (over photons and electrons, or hologram-allowing fields, or whatever). Or, even if they knew that QFT was true (and could allow for holograms!), I don't know that this knowledge would by itself allow the hologram-people to tell whether macroscopic/meta-electromagnetic phenomena in their ambit were being constructed with intellectual malice from some darker outside.

***One last "possibility."*** Again, if we're stipulating a close enough correspondence between the physics of the deceivers and that of the world that we really know of, then I'm assuming the computers involved (or maybe hypercomputers) use things like electricity. Maybe they're gluonium computers using color-charge on their logic gates (I can't even honestly say that the description I just conceived of is even faithful to the actual physics of gluons and generic (i.e. not just electric) charge theory, much less of computers/logic gates), who knows, but anyway, the victims would turn out to all be AIs, I suppose. If the simulation has various relevant affinities with the Internet (insofar as its programming/software base is distributed, in the distribution of the hardware), maybe the AIs could perform a subroutine in the simulation that the deceiver-programmers would not desire, something like an AI-generated computer-virus incident that causes electrical damage/overheating/whatever to the real-world machinery yielding the fake world.

So basically, depending on how finely we're parsing the phrase "same laws of physics as our world," I can at least vaguely imagine that it "might be possible" (would possibly be possible?) for the victim-world to trigger deceiver-world processes that noticeably fed back into the victim-world, *maybe* (just maybe) in a way that would offer the victims a chance at knowing about the deceivers.

Answer (score 0):

### Caveat

As a precursor, to discussion, see the following articles by working physicists:

- Sabine Hossenfelder's [Why the simulation hypothesis is pseudoscience](https://bigthink.com/thinking/why-the-simulation-hypothesis-is-pseudoscience/)
- Tim Andersen's [The universe is not a simulation.](https://medium.com/the-infinite-universe/you-cant-simulate-this-universe-a81106c66019)

### Short Answer

**The current consensus among professional thinkers is a no. There is [no empirical evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_evidence) that supports we are a running computer program and no scientific programme to test a scientific experiment.** Most of the arguments for it are [rationalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism) in nature. The simulation hypothesis is a [metaphysical argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics), not a scientific one. From Andersen:

> We can go on proposing finer and finer experiments, but we will always fail because the simulation theory is not a scientific theory. By this I mean that it cannot be falsified by experiment.

> It all comes down to the metaphysics of what is real and how do we know what is real which has a vast repertoire of alternatives to the ill posed simulation theory. These theories of ontology explain what there is. The simulation theory is an ontology theory that explains that what we think is there is simulated.

The belief otherwise is non-empirical pseudoscience according to mainstream scientists. From WP's "rationalism":

> In an old controversy, rationalism was opposed to empiricism, where the rationalists believed that reality has an intrinsically logical structure. Because of this, the rationalists argued that certain truths exist and that the intellect can directly grasp these truths. That is to say, rationalists asserted that certain rational principles exist in logic, mathematics, ethics, and metaphysics that are so fundamentally true that denying them causes one to fall into contradiction. The rationalists had such a high confidence in reason that empirical proof and physical evidence were regarded as unnecessary to ascertain certain truths

### Long Answer

A lot of people wonder about a host of related scenarios that are thought problems provoked by a form of [radical skepticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_skepticism) and an ambitious [rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism) that places a lot of weight in thought:

- [the butterfly dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhuangzi_(book)#.22The_Butterfly_Dream.22)
- [simulation hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis)
- [mathematical universe hypothesis](https://There%20is%20a%20lot%20o)
- [brain-in-a-vat scenario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_in_a_vat)
- [Descartes' demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_demon)
- [multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse)
- [modal realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_realism)

All of these scenarios posit some sort of alternative reality to the one we share and widely recognize as the reality of [scientific realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_realism). Seemingly, we enter the world predisposed to a [direct realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%C3%AFve_realism) of sorts, one in which our senses give us access to a public, shared connection to each other.

Your question is essentially, can and have we used [empirical evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_evidence) to rule-out or rule-in simulation of our universe. You will find that philosophers have different answers and will elaborate [metaphysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics) to justify yes or no in responding. However, since you are asking after empirical methods when you use "touch" let's give you some tools to decide for yourself:

- [Burden of Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)) - The claimant who claims there is an experiment that can prove it would have to defend such a thesis, and it would presumably be peer reviewed and accepted by scientists. I am aware of no such consensus that such an experiment exists and is widely accepted as capable.
- [Hitchen's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchens%27s_razor) - If you make a claim without evidence that requires evidence, one is not under any obligation to address it without evidence being provided. Hence, such conversations are metaphysical philosophy and not science proper.
- There are many [crackpots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_(person)) who peddle [woo](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Woo). There will be people who claim that they've even proven it already despite being rejected by the [mainstream science communities of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_of_sciences). If someone claims such evidence exists, be prepared to vet not just the argument, but the capacities of the claimant. Anyone on the Internet can claim anything anytime anywhere.
- Many philosophers believe in [epistemological methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology) besides empirical evidence. Besides rational and metaphysical argumentation, philosophers may use intuition, [brute facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_fact), and faith to arrive at conclusions. It is important that when dealing with the [rhetoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric) of this question, it is important also to consider the psychological and social truths involved in the situation. The dominant position of scientists who are primarily physicalists is one of [psychologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychologism): the mind emerges from the brain, or supervenes on it, or otherwise has some special connection. Any philosophical views that reject this are likely to be [pseudoscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscience) by the mainstream scientific community.

See [The simulation hypothesis is a dangerous illusion](https://bigthink.com/13-8/simulation-hypothesis-escapism/).

Comment: Good answer, +1.  However, this IS a testable claim, and BillOnne described two of the several tests one can do in his answer.  I list more in my comments on his answer.

Comment: @Dcleve I speak for the mainstream.  I have no objection to railing against the orthodoxy.  https://www.nbcnews.com/mach/science/what-simulation-hypothesis-why-some-think-life-simulated-reality-ncna913926

Comment: "The bottom line, Noack says, is that it’s impossible to test the simulation hypothesis as a whole."

Comment: Noack has not read Quine or Popper.  His "orthodoxy" is not philosophically mature.

Comment: @JD The "tools" that you're mentioning are just practical, but fallacious versions of "don't", right? Like the burden of proof is politeness not logic and the focus on academia is an argument from authority (heuristically valuable, still fallacious), Hitchen's Razor is good advice to avoid getting sucked into pointless discussions, though it's also not logic. The 3rd is a straight up ad hominem fallacy. The 4th is arguing it's a religion or pseudoscience?

Comment: @haxor789 Man is an irrational creature, and belief is governed more by psychological principle than logical principle. There are those incapable of experiencing disconfirmation and are highly suceptible to bias bias. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disconfirmed_expectancy

Comment: @haxor789 -- all claims have a "burden of support".  The request for consensus or proof is raising the bar too high, but the first point is basically valid. Hitchen's Razor is a fallacy itself, but is a pragmatic response to "prove me wrong" unsupported claims.  Woo put downs are just ad hominem fallacies, yes. Also yes, physicalism is a faith view held by the majority of scientists, and the dismissal of alternatives is generally by resorting to fallacies.  I score your critique of these tools as on target for  2.5/4.

Answer (score -1):

How about this thought example: **We're already living in a simulation.**
And we are pretty sure of that.

Like people who talk about simulations always like to take on the perspective of the creator-god that is omniscient overseer of the entire thing. But practically the way we perceive our environment already is a simulation. **"We" simulated "ourselves".**

Like we don't see reality. We make up our reality and what we see is a simulation of what we think reality looks like. Like colors aren't a thing. They are just electromagnetic signals that trigger reactions in our sensory inputs which can actually just detect mostly green and some red and blue and maybe black and white (not colors but the presence of absence of light). Everything else is made up. And even that red, green and blue are the color that they are and not just a signal being on and off is made up by our simulation.

None of what we see and experience is "real" at least not in the way that we experience it. But that is the world we actually live in. And it's easier for us to retreat into that world (become "insane") than to abandon it (even if we can intellectually argue it's not "real" we still perceive it as real). So for all intents and purpose we ARE living in a simulation (right?). Now some might argue that's cheating because the "real world" is still "real" and not a simulation (at least from what we know) and that that's the simulation that most of these simulation theory people are actually concerned with. But is it?

The thing is unless you believe that a simulation is something spiritual, non tangible, non-physical that can transcend the "real world" then you'd have to admit that any simulation likely runs on "real" hardware in "base reality" so what's the difference? We are living inside a simulation, inside of base reality. And within our simulation we became aware of the fact that we are living within a simulation. Which means despite living in a simulation we've still managed to live in the real world. We only experience the real world through our simulation and so certain things stay hidden from us, at least within the context of our simulation but we nevertheless are able to live both in a simulation and be aware of it and be an agent in the real world.

So apparently the answer seems to be yes, you can. However how we became conscious of our consciousness exactly...

Comment: Awareness is real and is supported by neural correlates of consciousness. The simulation of the universe is an untestable hypothesis and the subject of the Matrix. To suggest they are essentialy the same is false equivocation.

Comment: See [The universe is not a simulation.](https://medium.com/the-infinite-universe/you-cant-simulate-this-universe-a81106c66019)

Comment: That's not the point, the point is that our consciousness is a simulation of what is real, that it runs on real perceivable hardware was never questioned (by me).

Comment: Only if one fully accepts scientific instrumentalism. ; ) Not everyone has abandoned the doctrine of natural kinds.

Comment: what do you mean by that?